# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: namingStrategy

Tags: java, hibernate

There's an example from the web on how to use annotations in Hibernate (before that I've worked on the same example, but it used .xml instead. And I've managed to make it work without exceptions).
So now I have:

```
Initial session factory creation failedjava.lang.NoSuchFieldError: namingStrategy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at firstproject.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
at firstproject.StudentDAO.addSubject(StudentDAO.java:82)
at firstproject.Test.main(Test.java:12) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: namingStrategy
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.reset(AnnotationConfiguration.java:250)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:125)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:119)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:108)
at firstproject.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
... 2 more
```

Here is some code, that may help:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); // HibernateUtil.java:11
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial session factory creation failed" + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); // HibernateUtil.java:14
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}

public class StudentDAO {
    public Long addSubject(Subject subject) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); // StudentDAO.java:82
        session.beginTransaction();
        Long result = (Long) session.save(subject);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentDAO dao = new StudentDAO();
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setSubjectName("Mathematics");
        dao.addSubject(subject); // Test.java:12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hi Kleeo**

You have written the following line in **`HibernateUtil`** class.

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Replace this line of code with the below written line & retry. I hope this will work for you.

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try, but I did this only because it was in the example. So I don't know, if it's correct.

Comment: Yes definitely. Try it and if you will find this helpful for you then vote up the answer so that other people may also get some help from it.

Comment: How do I do this in xml? <bean name="cre:factorDatabaseSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="cre:factorDataSource" />
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
     org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
     org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
    </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
  <property name="packages

Answer (score 2):

AnnotationConfiguration has been Deprecated in Hibernate 3.6.

As you can see in the documentation (see link below) all functionality has been moved to Configuration.

You can use safely Configuration instead.

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

AnnotationConfiguration documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below :
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

And also ensure that your cfg.xml should be present in root of src folder. Else you will get exception of unable to find cfg file